# Loop through 2d array within a dictionary

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, dictionary, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am looping through all values in a 2d array which is held in a dictionary with the key `Band_1`

```
{'Band_1': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   ...,
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16)}
```

The code runs, but the array is 2650 x 2650 and I have 150+ dictionaries to process at each step, so it's very slow.

Note: for this example, there is only one key per dictionary, but that will not always be the case.

I have tried 3 different methods to loop through the array:

Method 1:

```
for key, bands in img.iteritems():
    for pixel in bands:
        for x in pixel:
            if x != noDataVal:
                x = x - dark_val
            else:
                x = noDataVal
```

Method 2:

```
for key, bands in img.iteritems():
    for pixel in bands.flat:
        if pixel != noDataVal:
            pixel = pixel - dark_val
        else:
            pixel = noDataVal
```

Method 3:

```
img = {k:[[i-dark_val for i in line if i != noDataVal] for line in data] for k, data in img.items()}
```

Method 4:

```
for key, band in image.iteritems():
    band = image[key]
    band_m = np.ma.masked_array(band, mask=noDataVal)
    band_m = band_m - dark_val
```

where:

```
dark_val = 75
noDataVal = 0
```

with `timeit` values over 5 loops as follows:

```
This is the first method: 18.446967368
This is the second method: 18.6967543083
This is the third method: 19.0136934398
This is the fourth method: 0.6860613911
```

**Any improvement on these methods in terms of speed/efficiency?**

Comment: The example array you posted has a lot of zeros, maybe using [`scipy.sparce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) will help? Or take a look [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40258/158849). Also in method 4, why do you redefine `band`?